# C# Selenium - Click/Clear/SendKeys not functioning properly, but works in Debug mode

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium

So I'm having an issue where my commands to change date fields only work half the time and I'm not sure what is causing this.  Yet, when I run them in Debug mode and go step-by-step thru the method, it does what it's suppose to do.  Below is the code that from my method:

```
PermitExpirationRangeStart = DateTime.Today.AddDays(121).ToShortDateString(); 
PermitExpirationRangeEnd = DateTime.Today.AddDays(150).ToShortDateString();
//Wait until we have the facility name.
//WaitFor(() => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(FindElement(By.Id("ctl32_ctl04_ctl05_txtValue")).GetAttribute("name")));
Sleep(5000);

FindElement(By.Id("ctl32_ctl04_ctl03_txtValue")).Clear();
FindElement(By.Id("ctl32_ctl04_ctl03_txtValue")).SendKeys(PermitExpirationRangeStart);
FindElement(By.Id("ctl32_ctl04_ctl05_txtValue")).Clear();
FindElement(By.Id("ctl32_ctl04_ctl05_txtValue")).SendKeys(PermitExpirationRangeEnd);
```

The page in question that I'm trying to test is the code below (this is just one of the date fields):

```
<td class="ParamEntryCell" style="padding-right:0px;">
  <div id="ctl32_ctl04_ctl05">
    <div style="white-space:nowrap;" onactivate="event.cancelBubble=true;">
      <input id="ctl32_ctl04_ctl05_txtValue" class="null" type="text" size="28" value="12/22/2016" name="ctl32$ctl04$ctl05$txtValue"/>
      <input id="ctl32_ctl04_ctl05_ddDropDownButton" type="image" style="cursor:pointer;" title="Select a value" alt="Select a value" name="ctl32$ctl04$ctl05$ddDropDownButton" src="/Reports/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&Version=12.0.4422.0&Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.calendar.gif"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
```

I've tried rearranging the lines of code in my test, I've even tried setting the elements to `IWebElements` before I do a Clear or `SendKeys` method on it.  Google search yields no results that helps figure this problem out.

Comment: If you are able to ouput some log, try put the log in between the find element. It could help you narrow down the problem.

Comment: What do you mean put the output log in between the find element?

When I was trying to figure out what the issue was when testing this, I did put 'console.writeline' commands in to see what is getting executed and what's not.  Sadly, that didn't help too much.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is most likely to be: you need to introduce wait in your code.

In debug mode, you executed your code "slowly" one step at a time, the browser instance has more than enough time to respond.

Please try introducing "Wait" mechanism.

`WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30); 
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("locator")));`

for both of your `ctl32_ctl04_ctl03_txtValue` and `ctl32_ctl04_ctl05_txtValue` elements

Answer (score 1):

May be you are facing problem due to execution speed,  Here due to fast execution sometime selenium doesn't focus to the input before setting value. You should try using `.Click()` to provide focus to the element before setting the value as below :-

```
IWebElement el = driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl32_ctl04_ctl03_txtValue"));
el.Click();
el.Clear();
el.SendKeys(PermitExpirationRangeStart);

IWebElement el1 = FindElement(By.Id("ctl32_ctl04_ctl05_txtValue"));
el1.Click();
el1.Clear();
el1.SendKeys(PermitExpirationRangeEnd);
```

**Note**: No need to find element again and again in the same page. You need to find just one time and stored into a variable for further action.

Hope it helps..:)

Answer (score 0):

```
Element.SendKeys("");
Element.SendKeys(number);
```